# Generate data using Python and export to excel file

Tags: python, excel, file, csv

I'm very much a beginner. This generates the "right" data off the URL, but when I try to generate a CSV file, the resultant Excel file is empty.
This is the code ...

```
import csv
import urllib.request
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

f = open('dataoutput.csv', 'w', newline = "")
writer = csv.writer(f)

soup = BeautifulSoup(urllib.request.urlopen("https://www.rjobrien.co.uk/tools/quoteresult/symbol/FGBLM8").read(), 'lxml')

tbody = soup('table', {"class": "table table-bordered table-condensed"})[0].find_all('tr')

for row in tbody:
    cols = row.findChildren(recursive=False)
    cols = [ele.text.strip() for ele in cols]

writer.writerow(cols)
```

Comment: Make sure you close the file so all data is flushed to the file.  Better, use a `with` statement to automatically close the file.

Comment: Fiddling around, below seems to work fine ...

Comment: import csv
import urllib.request
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

                
try:
    soup = BeautifulSoup(urllib.request.urlopen("https://www.rjobrien.co.uk/tools/quoteresult/symbol/FGBLM8").read(), 'lxml')
except:
    pass
tbody = soup('table', {"class": "table table-bordered table-condensed"})[0].find_all('tr')

for row in tbody:
    dataDB = row.findChildren(recursive=False)
    dataDB = [ele.text.strip() for ele in dataDB]

with open('DB.csv', 'w', newline = "") as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f, quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL)
    writer.writerow(dataDB)

Comment: Code in a comment is unreadable. Edit your question, or answer it if you solved it.

Answer (score 0):

Did you mean to put the `writerow()` after the loop?  As written, it will produce only the last row.

I assume you do `f.close()` sometime later.  I recommend using `with` which will close the file at the end of scope.  For example,

```
with open('dataoutput.csv', 'w', newline = "") as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    ...
```

Comment: Yes - I only need the last row of the output. Although print(cols) generates the correct output, the CSV Excel file it generates is empty, i.e. the data isn't being 'sent' to the CSV file

Answer (score 0):

You should indent `<tab>writer.writerow(cols)` with the same identation as the loop.

You should `f.close()` when you finished writing the file. Python should do it automatically, but you never know when it will do it, and you are using system resources (there is a limited number of file open in parallel).

Eventually you could add as first line: `sep=,` so that you will have no problem with different Excel locales. See https://superuser.com/questions/407082/easiest-way-to-open-csv-with-commas-in-excel

Comment: the 's' had no effect - still not getting the data into the CSV file ...